# How do you retrieve the size of Cassandra list?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

If I have a table in cassandra where the schema is like the following:

name varchar

email list(text)

If I have a list of email addresses for each name, how do I get the size of the list for the user?
Like if user1 has e1@yahoo.com and e2@gmail.com. The list would contain these two emails. What I want is that it returns 2 for the number of emails the user has.
I'm using Cassandra 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax support for that in CQL https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5313